# Microsoft ADB2C bookmarking the tenant url instead of login/home page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that uses ADB2C .

If the user happens to bookmark the tenant url -
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_signin_signup&response_type=token%20id_token&client_id=xxx&state=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmylogin.com%2F&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fmytenant.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fapp.read&nonce=xxx

instead of the login page (mylogin.com), the user is first tried to login with a state and since invalid, the user is then re-directed to the login page.

This creates a bad user experience.

Is this the general behavior expected in this scenario.

Is there a way to modify it so that feel like seamless login (myapp.com --> adb2c --> my app invalid --> myapp login --> adb2c )

I hope I have clarified the scenario.(Note I can add custom domain but that would just be branding but flow would still be same correct?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Users should not be bookmarking that URL.
The URL you show includes the `nonce`, which is a single-use value.
The application will setup the expected value for this before authenticating the user.
Since it won't be expecting anything at this point, it won't know what to do with the response.
The user must go through your application to sign in.

Comment: I understand that users should not be bookmarking that URL but some do (I am trying to understand if other than educating them is it possible to be fail-proof). In this case The application tries to login twice (one with the invalid state) and then proper login. My question is when bookmarking the url I face this issue of attempted login twice, but when the token has expired I need to only signin once (expected) . Isn't an expired state also the case of bookmarked url?

Comment: In this case the application does not attempt to sign in twice. The user triggers auth once, app rejects it and requires signing in again. Though if the user signed in on that request, the user shouldn't actually see the login screen again as their session with B2C should have been established anyway (unless you specify something like prompt=login).

Comment: We are facing the same issue and it is really annoying. I keep on getting (new) users that have issue with the login, and when supporting them, it appears they have bookmarked the login page and not the original URL. Documentation is helping only for those that read it.

@user14013917 Did you find a solution that worked?